# Plone: plonesocial.auth.rpx->rpx_login_form was not found

Tags: plone, rpx, plone-3.x

Tried to use rpx login form; the page was finally redirected to `http://site_name/rpx_login_form`

Got error:
This page does not seem to exist…

We apologize for the inconvenience, but the page you were trying to access is not at this address. You can use the links below to help you find what you are looking for.

If you are certain you have the correct web address but are encountering an error, please contact the Site Administration.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the `rpx_skins` skin layer hasn't been properly registered. Check your skin  layer configurations (in ZMI -> `portal_skins` -> properties).

*Disclaimer:* I have never used this add-on, I only looked over the [BitBucket source repository](https://bitbucket.org/cryu/plonesocial.auth.rpx/).

Comment: Thanks, I just installed their version,replaced files&folders and it worked! Probably there was some prblem with links and paths

Comment: Can you please describe how to check the skins layer configurations?

Comment: @Adripants: By looking at the `portal_skins` tool in the ZMI. The `properties` tab shows current skin layers per theme; check if `rpx_skins` is listed.

Comment: (the down vote must have been an accident, sorry, if you edit the answer I can change it)